# How to see my Cycles render and blender render in Game engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine

This has probably been asked several times but I can't seem to be finding the answer.

I currently have made a tree (the body in Blender game and the textures in cycles render). Now I want to check it out in the game I'm making.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Cycles materials in the BGE; it uses something similar to the Blender Internal renderer with a few differences. You can still use the same model, though—you'll just have to change the material.

Comment: Thought so. Though why does Cycles end up being more realistic than game engine?

Comment: Cycles uses a much more advanced material lighting transport model than the game engine, which is why it's more realistic.